# i want to set my image size as I wish and this my script of date picker

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jsp

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#dateOfBirth" ).datepicker({
      showOn: "button",
      buttonImage: "Pictures/calendicon.jpg",
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      buttonText: "Select date"
    });
  });
</script>
```

This is my script i want to adjust the size of buttonImage

Comment: you can adjust the size of your image via CSS

Comment: Give a example where you can change it by css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust the size of your image via CSS.

```
img.ui-datepicker-trigger {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your custom css as your need

```
<style>
.ui-datepicker-trigger { position:relative;top:{}px ;right:{}px ; height:{}px }
 /* {} is the value according to your need */
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is following css can change size or other properties of button:

```
.ui-datepicker-trigger{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/djtdnpb7/)